# How to remove line spaces in UITextView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitextview

I have a textView, in that I am entering the data and I pressed on the enter it is going to next line and I entered some other data and I saved it.

The result I am getting is :

[image: notes]

And it is stored in services like :

```
{"PersonID":9416,"PeriodID":59130,"Notes":"tyyyttyt
ttrtrtrt
ttttrtrtr","PeriodDate":"2015-05-08T10:50:00"}
```

But my requirement is that the string should be stored as :

> tyyyyttyt ttrttrt ttttrtrtr

I searched in google but I didn't get answer for this.

Can any one please help me to sort out this problem ?

I am very new to Objective C topics.

Comment: Replace the '\n' with the ' ' in string & then see..

Comment: @KOUSHIK try my answer it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Where actually to replace?

Comment: `NSLog` this `notes` key-value and show us the result please

Comment: I edited your question to actually include the image and I added some formatting. Feel free to click on the edit button if you wish to change anything !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To remove new line from your string use following code:

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
```

where `myString` is the text you fetch from your `UITextView`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77197/discussion-on-answer-by-vivek-molkar-how-to-remove-line-spaces-in-uitextview-in).

Comment: @Koushikmaley this answer not works for me how you accepted it. please clear out it.

Answer (score -1):

Separate your string in components separated by any new line character, then join them again to a new string, separating them with a space:

```
NSString *cleanString = [[myTextField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it. Replace Double Space with Single space.

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.textView.text length]; i++) 
{
   self.textView.text=[self.textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];

}
```

Comment: @KOUSHIKMALEY Try this answer. and replay.